# How do I perform a dynamic select in Linq?

Tags: linq, select, dynamic

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically specify the properties for my select clause in a linq query.

Lets say I have a collection of employee objects.  At run time, the end user will be specifying which properties they would like to see for those employees, so I need to be able to dynamically construct my Linq select clause.

I have used the dynamic Linq library, but I prefer not to use that, because it requires me to build a string to pass to the select method.  I'd like to understand how to do this via Expressions.

Comment: Check out [Scott Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It will explain exactly how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you select all properties of the Employee object and just display the ones the User has selected? It usually doesn't make much difference if you select a few or all columns of a DB row (except for some large columns maybe).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx) looks like something that fits more with your requirements of not using dynamic linq.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection to get the dynamic Column Values

> //columns variable has column name as comma separated String which you
>   can save in DB  //example string columns ="Name,Id,Age";

```
   var strColumns =columns.split(,);
    foreach(var myObject in MyObjectcollection)
   {
    for(int index =0;index<strColumns.count();index++)
    {
    //Create a collection of objects 
    mycollection.add(myObject.GetType().GetProperty(strColumns[index]).GetValue(myObject, null));
    }
  }
```